# VB.Net How to Combine 2 Lists

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 listboxes.
listbox1 contains variable account names,

```
John
James
Matt
```

Second listbox contains a non-variable script

```
Dear <account name>
Thank you for contacting us.
We will get back to you soon.
```

I will loop thru account names. I have the code for that.
But how can I get output on the 3rd listbox or textbox as below;

```
Dear John
Thank you for contacting us.
We will get back to you soon.

Dear James
Thank you for contacting us.
We will get back to you soon.

Dear Matt
Thank you for contacting us.
We will get back to you soon.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you are using a ListBox for your static text, but this code should do what you want it to do.
I am using `For Each` to iterate through the Object Collections of both of your Listboxes converting the resulting objects to strings then adding the modified lines to a List(Of String) then assigning it to the TextBox's Lines Property.  See if this works for you.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim result As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
    For Each item As Object In ListBox1.Items
        For Each line As Object In ListBox2.Items
            result.Add(CStr(line).Replace("<account name>", CStr(item))) 'Modify line and add to List
        Next
        result.Add("") 'Add seperator
        TextBox1.Lines = result.ToArray() 'Have to convert to String Array since that is what Lines is
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I appreciate it, it worked great. I'm a beginner, I thought using listboxes would be easier for me, I will look for other possible options as well. Thanks again

Comment: @ValeriaKaya You are welcome I am Glad to be of help, The reason I mentioned the Listbox's is that they are a collection of objects not strings, therefore the need to use CStr to convert the Items to a usable form.